# Reference text from cell and return remaining text to other cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So my question is... I have 2 columns, A and B. In B I want to read the text from A (which has a list of texts: eg. Normal Car, Lorry, Sports Car, Bike) and I would type some text specified from the list in 'A' (eg. Bike) and in B would be the text that is left from that list from 'A' (So meaning "Normal Car", "Lorry" and "Sports Car" would be shown in 'B')

How do I do that?

[image: Here is a manually made example:]

This is the spreadsheet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16o75-R-U3zY0vajg1pO0N7-t9uGCtt_B2QiZLW_sXUM/edit#gid=0

Here are all the words that will be used: **Lyrics, Visualizer, Bass Boost, 8D, Nightcore, Image Only**

What I want to achieve is if I fill one or more of the words in Column A, then all the rest of the words will be filled up in B automatically. I left them filled up already so you can see the example. Thanks.

Comment: Added more info with link to the spreadsheet and example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### for one word:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 REGEXREPLACE("Lyrics, Visualizer, Bass Boost, 8D, Nightcore, Image Only,", 
 A1:A&",", ), )), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

#### for multiple words:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A1:A), SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXREPLACE({"Lyrics", "Visualizer", "Bass Boost", "8D", "Nightcore", "Image Only"}, 
 REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, ", ", "|"), ), " ", "♦"), )),,999^99))), " ", ", "), "♦", " "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I would type some text specified from the list in 'A' (eg. Bike) and in B would be the text that is left from that list from

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.*)"&B1:B)), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey thanks but what i want is something else, please check my newly added comments in the post! I added an example and also the spreadsheet. Thanks!